# c# WSDL without Header but requested

Tags: c#, soap, header, wsdl

Even if the application is similar to one made recently, rephrase in the correct terms, maybe I can better understand what my problem, since I have so far tried unsuccessfully a solution and the ones I found were not for the My case

Abstract: first time I'm dealing with web service, soap, appurtenances, so forgive me ignorance absolute. (Also for the bad english)

I have a wsdl on a web server institutional written in java that does NOT contain the client and the various calls no header, but it always requires, for each call.

Problem: I create the client quietly with the endpoint, I connect to the web server responds to me and I read all the parameters (which I do not need anything) of the server. (So ​​I created the tunnel)

Just try to make a call using any of the wsdl, type wsdl.result res = wsdl.getvalore (parameters), I always get errors due to the lack of the header in the message, for example: Private key is not in the X.509 certificate. (But NOT required private key to feel the support of the web service) or No Security Header.

Following the example of the soap message in XML. For the part BODY no problem, but how do I add the header?
Thanks to everyone who can help me out.
Regards.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
   <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-3">
    <wsu:Created>2014-09-09T08:23:50.725Z</wsu:Created>
    <wsu:Expires>2014-09-09T08:28:50.725Z</wsu:Expires>
   </wsu:Timestamp>
   <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-00000000000000000000000000000000">qtgOKG92iPHI/XLXGxFmg6Vnqmdg=</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
   <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-4">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
     <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
      <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="soapenv"/>
     </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
     <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
     <ds:Reference URI="#TS-3">
      <ds:Transforms>
       <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsse soapenv"/>
       </ds:Transform>
      </ds:Transforms>
      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
      <ds:DigestValue>hK3A/dZmQfIGDx9p7/8zV31iWDQ=</ds:DigestValue>
     </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>JlWXCRS6NEz9pl5gD9PBedQj6OMxBDXkLhIwGjncl4IsC1DzPoIVEJmIp/D679ba+pi692gvGpLn</ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-00000000000000000000000000000000">
     <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-00000000000000000000000000000000">
      <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-00000000000000000000000000000000" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
     </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
   </ds:Signature>
  </wsse:Security>
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <scat:getPrescrizioneFirmata xmlns:scat="www.aaa.regione.it/Schemas/AAA_WEB/SERVICE/">
   <scat:datiOperatore>
    <scat:codStruttura>001001</scat:codStruttura>
    <scat:codiceFiscale>PPPTTT00P01R000T</scat:codiceFiscale>
    <scat:ruoloIstituzionale>Rrr000000</scat:ruoloIstituzionale>
   </scat:datiOperatore>
   <scat:datiApplicativo>
    <scat:applDigest>gredfgggjnbhtdybvvhghggvvbvb=</scat:applDigest>
    <scat:created>2014-09-09T10:23:522+0200</scat:created>
    <scat:nome>ABC</scat:nome>
    <scat:nonce>ZQJzbirixuhvfa8NtoQa</scat:nonce>
    <scat:produttore>PIPPO</scat:produttore>
    <scat:versione>20.03</scat:versione>
   </scat:datiApplicativo>
   <scat:identificativoRicetta>001001001001001</scat:identificativoRicetta>
  </scat:getPrescrizioneFirmata>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>​
```